# How long is the output of EncryptByPassPhrase(), relative to the input?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, encryption

I'm starting an encryption project, using `EncryptByPassPhrase()`, mostly on `VARCHAR` values.  Naturally, the encrypted values are longer than the originals.  Is there a formula I can use to calculate how long I need to make the new `VARBINARY` fields, so as to hold any possible value of the original `VARCHAR` field?

E.g., the first field I examined has values of up to 37 characters in length, and the encrypted values are up to 100 bytes; another has values up to 50 chars and encrypted values are up to 124 bytes.  However, values as short as two or three characters can encrypt to 76 bytes.  If I size the new fields as 75 + X bytes, will I have room to store the encrypted version of any possible text value of length X or less?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as my testing goes (using SQL Server Express 2014, SP1 and SQL Server Developer 2012 SP2, both 64-it), the formula *when **not** using an authenticator* for the return value (`VARBINARY`) length of:

```sql
ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('_My_PassPhr@zE_yo_', {anything})
```

is:

```sql
28 + (8 * (DATALENGTH(@ClearText) / 8))
```

Try the following:

```sql
DECLARE @ClearText VARCHAR(8000);
SET @ClearText = 'testdfdf gkdj flkgjdlfkgjdlf gjlf gklf TE%$%^&^%HFGHFhg fkgh jfgkhæ';

SELECT LEN(ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('_My_PassPhr@zE_yo_', @ClearText)) AS [ActualLength],
       28 + (8 * (DATALENGTH(@ClearText) / 8)) AS [EstimatedLength];
```

Returns:

```
ActualLength    EstimatedLength
92              92
```

And, if you change the datatype of `@ClearText` to instead be `NVARCHAR(4000)`, and run it again, it returns:

```
ActualLength    EstimatedLength
156             156
```

**Note:** the formula *looks* like it can be reduced by cancelling out the `8`s. However, that will cause it to not work correctly since it is banded-ranges of datalengths that fit into a "bucket":

```
input bytes    result length
-----------    -------------
 1 -  7        28
 8 - 15        36
16 - 23        44
24 - 31        52
```

So the `(DATALENGTH(@ClearText) / 8)` portion of the formula is enforcing that decimal values are ignored rather than the value be rounded. And that is accomplished by default behavior of dividing two INT values ;-).

---

**UPDATE:**

The testing done above does not use an option available to [ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190357.aspx): specifying an "authenticator". Doing so adds 16 bytes to the minimum length, and then while the increments are still in 8-byte steps, and while the banded-ranges are still 8 bytes each, the initial range is only 4 bytes so the ranges are offset by 4 as compared to the range boundaries when not using an authenticator. To help illustrate, the following chart shows the ranges and their corresponding result lengths:

```
input bytes    result length
-----------    -------------
 0 -  3        44
 4 - 11        52
12 - 19        60
20 - 27        68
```

The formula *when using an authenticator* for the return value (`VARBINARY`) length of:

```sql
ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('_My_PassPhr@zE_yo_', {anything}, 1, {anything_1-128_bytes})
```

is:

```sql
44 + (8 * ((DATALENGTH(@ClearText) + 4) / 8))
```

NOTES:

- The length of `PassPhrase` has no effect on the result length
- An empty string for `PassPhrase` has no effect on the result length
- In order for an `Authenticator` value to have any effect, the value of `Add_Authenticator` (the 3rd input parameter) must be set to `1`
- The length of `Authenticator` has no effect on the result length *as long as it is at least 1*.
- An empty string for `Authenticator` will have an effect on the result length, and that effect is the same as setting `Add_Authenticator` to `0`.
- If either `Add_Authenticator` is set to `0`, or `Authenticator` is an empty string or `NULL`, then the formula is the same as if there was no "authenticator".

The following is an expanded and improved test that shows both with and without an "authenticator", and makes it easier to change the `@PassPhrase` value:

```sql
DECLARE @ClearText NVARCHAR(4000),
        @Authenticator sysname,
        @PassPhrase VARCHAR(100);

SET @PassPhrase = '_My_PassPhr@zE_yo_';
SET @ClearText = 'testdfdf gkdj flkgjdlfkgjdlf gjlf gklf TE%$%^&^%HFGHFhg fkgh jfgkhæ';
SET @Authenticator = REPLICATE(N' ', 128);

SELECT LEN(ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@PassPhrase, @ClearText))
                                         AS [ActualLengthSansAuthenticator],
       28 + (8 * (DATALENGTH(@ClearText) / 8)) AS [EstimatedLengthSansAuthenticator];

SELECT LEN(ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(@PassPhrase, @ClearText, 1, @Authenticator))
                                         AS [ActualLengthWithAuthenticator],
       44 + (8 * ((DATALENGTH(@ClearText) + 4) / 8)) AS [EstimatedLengthWithAuthenticator];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not scientific; the only way to get the scientific answer would be to look at the code the SQL Server developers used to implement the 3DES 128 algorithm.

Having said that, built a quick test rig that attempts to determine the practical length of the encrypted text.

```
;WITH Num1
AS 
(
SELECT TOP(4000) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.object_id, o1.object_id)
    , pwd = REPLICATE('x', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.object_id, o1.object_id))
FROM sys.objects o, sys.objects o1
)
, Num2
AS 
(
SELECT TOP(4000) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.object_id, o1.object_id)
    , dat = REPLICATE('x', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.object_id, o1.object_id))
FROM sys.objects o, sys.objects o1
)
SELECT Encrypted = ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(pwd,dat,1,CONVERT(VARBINARY(20), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY num1.rn, num2.rn)))
    , EncryptedLength = LEN(ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(pwd,dat,1,CONVERT(VARBINARY(20), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY num1.rn, num2.rn))))
    , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY num1.rn, num2.rn)
    , DatLen = LEN(dat)
    , Diff = LEN(ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE(pwd,dat,1,CONVERT(VARBINARY(20), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY num1.rn, num2.rn)))) - LEN(dat)
FROM Num1, Num2;
```

This generates passphrases and data of varying length between 1 and 4000 bytes, then compares the output of the `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE` function with length of the inputted data.  I've found, on my computer, there is between 41 and 48 "extra" bytes in the output.

Having said that, I would suggest using `VARBINARY(8000)` as the field size since that is the defined maximum output for the function.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this to determine the length of the varbinary data after enxrypting with enryptbypassphrase

```
CEILING((CAST(DATALENGTH(@cleartext) as float) + 1) / 8) * 8 + 20
```